# Create private key after CSR creation and p7b generation

Tags: certificate, private-key, csr

I'm having trouble understanding how to get/generate a private key for some certificates I requested.

I've created a CSR using the DigiCert Certificate Utility for Windows, which gave me a csr.txt file as an output but no .key file.

Then I proceeded to request the certificates by inserting the above mentioned CSR in the Certificate Management portal of my company.
Now I have received the p7b files and the related CSRs, but no private keys: is it possible to generate it now?

Thanks in advance,
Tommaso

Comment: *...is it possible to generate it now?...* No.

Answer (score 0):

Use the import function of the DigiCert Certificate Utility for Windows. The key is stored on software in the machine where the CSR was created. After the import the key and the certificate are associated and should be in the Windows certificate Store. If the key was generated with the exportable flag, you can export a PKCS#12 and convert that to a key file using openSSL.